# how to do two way data-binding to a complex object in angularjs asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

```
 <div class="section-form" ng-repeat="headings in QuestionsMain">
 <p>{{headings.Title}}</p>

 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="section in headings.FormSection">
  <h3>{{ section.Title }}</h3>
  <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="group in section.FormGroups">  
  <div>{{ group.Title }}</div>
  <div class="" ng-repeat="questions in group.FormQuestions">
  <h4>{{ questions.QuestionName }} </h4>
   <ul >
  <li ng-repeat="answers in questions.FormAnswers">
  <input type="radio" name="content" value="{{ answers.AnswerCode }}" id="{{ answers.FormAnswer_ID }}" />
<label for="{{ answers.FormAnswer_ID }}" class="radio-style"></label>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
 var eval = angular.module('evalQuestions', []);

 //$scope.QuestionsMain contains json data
 eval.controller('EvalController', ['$scope', 'questions', function ($scope, questions) {
        questions.success(function (data) {

            $scope.QuestionsMain = JSON.parse(data.d);

        });
    }]);


//calling webmethod for getting json data
 eval.factory('questions', ['$http', function ($http) {

return ttp.post('EvaluationTest.aspx/GetEvaluationQuestionandAnswerDetails', { "evalNumber": 1, "languageCode": 'en' })
    .success(function (data) {

        return data;
    })
    .error(function (err) {
        alert(err);
    });
    }]);
```

---

this is the json data received from my webmethod

```
[  
   {  

      "Title":"Test Title 1",

      "FormSection":[  
         {  
            "ContentType":"GENR",
            "Title":"Test section 1",

            "FormGroups":[  
               {  

                  "Title":"Test Group 1",,

                  "FormQuestions":[  
                     {  

                        "QuestionName":"rate your course?",                  
                        "QuestionCode":"100",
                        "FormAnswers":[  
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Excellent",

                              "AnswerCode":"5"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Very good",

                              "AnswerCode":"4"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Good",

                              "AnswerCode":"3"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Fair",

                              "AnswerCode":"2"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Poor",

                              "AnswerCode":"1"

                           }
                        ]
                     },
                      {  

                        "QuestionName":"rate your food?",                  
                        "QuestionCode":"200",
                        "FormAnswers":[  
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Excellent",

                              "AnswerCode":"5"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Very good",

                              "AnswerCode":"4",

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Good",

                              "AnswerCode":"3",

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Fair",

                              "AnswerCode":"2",

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Poor",

                              "AnswerCode":"1",

                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "ContentType":"GENR2",
            "Title":"Test section 2",

            "FormGroups":[  
               {  

                  "Title":"Test Group 2",,

                  "FormQuestions":[  
                     {  

                        "QuestionName":"rate your teacher?",                  
                        "QuestionCode":"300",
                        "FormAnswers":[  
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Excellent",

                              "AnswerCode":"5"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Very good",

                              "AnswerCode":"4"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Good",

                              "AnswerCode":"3"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Fair",

                              "AnswerCode":"2"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Poor",

                              "AnswerCode":"1"

                           }
                        ]
                     },
                      {  

                        "QuestionName":"rate your course content?",                  
                        "QuestionCode":"400",
                        "FormAnswers":[  
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Excellent",

                              "AnswerCode":"5"

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Very good",

                              "AnswerCode":"4",

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Good",

                              "AnswerCode":"3",

                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Fair",

                              "AnswerCode":"2",



                           },
                           {  

                              "AnswerName":"Poor",

                              "AnswerCode":"1",

                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }

      ]
   }
]
```

my asp.net page looks like the below

```
rate your teacher?   5 4 3 2  1  (these are radio buttons)
rate your class?     5 4 3 2  1  (these are radio buttons)
rate your food?      5 4 3 2  1  (these are radio buttons)
```

the html given above may not be proper but i think you can get the context of it.
I can bind the data properly. now i want to get questioncode and selected answercode and save the same to  database on click of submit button.

is two way data binding possible here? please let me know one or more possible ways of achieving the same.

Comment: What is not working? 2way data-binding is the default behaviour of angular

Comment: @jean-philippe - my problem here is how to get the selected answercodes and questioncodes into an object  and save it to database. im little confused how to get these values into an object and where to write that piece of code in the above example

Answer (score 0):

Your factory does not need to implement the success (if you want to do so, you have to return a promise (with the $q service)). imoo, in your case, using a service instead of a factory is best practice (services are singletons).

```
eval.service('questions', ['$http', function ($http) {

    var service;
    service.getEval = $http.post('EvaluationTest.aspx/GetEvaluationQuestionandAnswerDetails', { "evalNumber": 1, "languageCode": 'en' });
}]);
    return service;
```

Then, inside your controller, you can implement the promise :

```
eval.controller('EvalController', ['$scope', 'questions', function ($scope, questions) {
    questions.getEval().then(function (data) {

        $scope.QuestionsMain = data;

    }, function(error){
        // Handle error here
    });

    $scope.save = function(){
        // Call your question service here and save the object you will give him.
    };

}]);
```

I think your view is correct (or almost). The 2-way data binding will be made automatically by angular.

edit :

to call your save function from the view, you just have to add the directive `ng-click`

eg :

```
<input type="button" ng-click="save()" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Could you please give the code for how to read selected radio button value(answercode) and questioncode and also how to bind answercode and questioncode to make them two way binding compatible. Thanks

Comment: I never use radio buttons, so I have no idea. If you can read it on the view, the 2-way binding will work directly